# Overflow.Exception crashing my program

Tags: vb.net, memory, overflow, rpm

I know this is how it's supposed to be done however, in VB.NET it gives me an overflow exception crashing my program. If there is any "VB.NET equivalent" of doing this, help is much appreciated.

```
Dim hActiveWeapon = _mem.rdInt(GetLocalBase() + &H2EE8)
Dim wepEntity = _mem.rdInt(_client + Offsets.EntityList + ((hActiveWeapon & &HFFF) - 1) * &H10) ' Crashes here @ hActiveWeapon & &HFFF
Dim wepIndex = _mem.rdInt(wepEntity + Offsets.iItemDefinitionIndex)
```

I am doing this to get the lower 12 bytes of m_hActiveWeapon (0xFFF = 0b111111111111 = 4095), so I can get the index of the active weapon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meh the answer was simple, changing "&" to "And" fixed it.